# Unable to use JFrog Artifactory to proxy GitHub private repositories as Go Registry

Tags: go, artifactory

I want to use Go Remote repository proxying Github. I have created Go remote repo github proxying https://github.com/ and I have created a Go virtual repository as well. Credentials added as mentioned in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Go+Registry#GoRegistry-RemoteRepositories.

I did everything explained on the link above but when I tried to get the modules I get that:

```
go env -w GONOSUMDB="*github.com/xxx/*"
export GOPROXY="https://test:%5Bredacted%5D@xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/go/go"
go mod download -x
get https://test:%5Bredacted%5D@xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/go/go/github.com/xxx/platform/@v/v0.21.0.mod
get https://test:%5Bredacted%5D@xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/go/go/github.com/xxx/platform/@v/v0.21.0.mod: 404 Not Found (0.894s)
go: github.com/xxx/platform@v0.21.0: reading https://test:%5Bredacted%5D@xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/go/go/github.com/xxx/platform/@v/v0.21.0.mod: 404 Not Found
```

Besides that, I can get public modules from github. Auth seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to JFrog Artifactory 6.19+ or 7.4.0+ as this was a missing feature until then (https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-19395).